# Interesting limit involving hordes of logarithms.

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

> $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\ln (x\ln a)\ln \left(\dfrac{\ln ax}{\ln\frac xa}\right)=6$$
>   Find the value of $a$.
>
> Answer: $e^3$

This struck me as an interesting problem and wanted to know if there are any more methods to solve it except the one I have used (written as an answer below).

Thanks!

Edit: for those requiring additional context, I have **SOLVED** the problem and my solution is posted below as an answer. I am merely looking for other ways to solve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall make two substitutions which will be really useful.
First, let $\ln a=b$. The left hand side of the equation becomes,
$$(\ln x+\ln b)\ln\left(\dfrac{\ln x +b}{\ln x - b}\right)$$
Now, the second substitution: $\ln x=y$. Since $x\to 0^+\Rightarrow y\to -\infty$

So the limit now transforms to
$$\lim_{y\to -\infty}(y+\ln b)\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{2b}{y-b}\right)$$

Using the limit

> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$

We get the limit to be
$$\lim_{y\to-\infty}\frac{2b(y+\ln b)}{y-b}=2b=6$$
Hence we have $b=3\Rightarrow a=e^3$.

Comment: Note that $x\to0^+\implies y=\ln(x)\to-\infty$.

Comment: Apologies, fixed that.

Comment: Your substitutions simplify the visual look of the problem considerably. +1

Comment: (+1) For what it's worth, I think this is exactly how I would have handled the problem. Maybe you should think again! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Thank you! Firstly, I don't understand what you want me "think again" about. Secondly, **How did you get that smiley?** :P

Comment: As the smiley was meant to indicate, I was just making a self-deprecating joke. Perhaps I was just being British, or perhaps I was just being me. (See, there I go again!) As for the smiley itself, I shamelessly copied it from José Carlos Santos (@josé-carlos-santos), who used it recently in a comment on something I'd posted. It was new to me, too! Nice, isn't it? `\smile` is an ordinary $\LaTeX{}$ binary relation symbol. `\ddot` is an ordinary $\LaTeX{}$ maths accent, which puts two dots on top of a symbol. But the effect looks like magic, doesn't it?

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Nice! But you haven't answered the first question I posed. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to explain my own joke. (I'm hopeless at making jokes in Real Life, and probably almost as bad on the Net!) The point was that if I would be likely to go about solving the problem in the same way, that might not count as a recommendation of the method! (But as I say, I was joking; I *do* like the method.)

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley Okaay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\log ax}{\log\dfrac xa}=1+\frac{2\log a}{\log\dfrac xa}$$ so that

$$\log\frac{\log ax}{\log\dfrac xa}\sim\frac{2\log a}{\log\dfrac xa}.$$

As the denominator will simplify with $\log(x\log a))$, we are left with

$$2\log a=6.$$

Comment: That's exactly what I have; I have simply labelled $\log a$ to be $b$ and $\log x$ to be $y$.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar: is it astonishing that we come to the same answer ?

Comment: I guess not :P BTW in my previous comment I missed "done" before the semi-colon.